# Fatal error: Class 'Demo_Test_Helper_Data' not found in F:\wamp\www\magentodemo\app\Mage.php on line 546

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Please Help me what is my fault in set up of custom helper class in magento

Fatal error: Class 'Demo_Test_Helper_Data' not found in F:\wamp\www\magentodemo\app\Mage.php on line 546

#### Folder sturcture

config.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
        <global>
                <models>
                        <test>
                            <class>Demo_Test_Model</class>
                        </test>
                </models>
                <blocks>
                        <test>
                            <class>Demo_Test_Block</class>
                        </test>
                </blocks>
                <helpers>
                        <test>
                            <class>Demo_Test_Helper</class>
                        </test>
                </helpers>
        </global>
</config>`
```

Data.php

```
`<?php
class Demo_Test_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
}
?>`
```

In app/etc/modules/Data_Test.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
        <modules>
                <Demo_Test>
                        <active>true</active>
                        <codePool>local</codePool>
                </Demo_Test>
        </modules>
</config>`
```

Call Helper class in test.php file From root directory

```
`<?php 
require_once "app/Mage.php";
Mage::app();
$helper = Mage::helper("test");
?>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to below config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <modules>
    <Demo_Test>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Demo_Test>
  </modules>
  <config>
        <global>
                <models>
                        <test>
                            <class>Demo_Test_Model</class>
                        </test>
                </models>
                <blocks>
                        <test>
                            <class>Demo_Test_Block</class>
                        </test>
                </blocks>
                <helpers>
                        <test>
                            <class>Demo_Test_Helper</class>
                        </test>
                </helpers>
        </global>
</config>`
```

Comment: I got following error  Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Test_Helper_Data' not found in F:\wamp\www\magentodemo\app\Mage.php on line 546

Comment: please try to remove your magento cache